# WooCommerce overriding generate_product_data in WC_Structured_Data

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Currently a website I am working on shows prices in Ex Vat with the inc Vat price underneath. I have a problem that the structured data is showing the ex Vat price, which is showing as a warning in Google merchant centre as they want the inc Vat price.

I have a added a function to my functions.php to override this and get the price including tax and this works except when it comes to removing the old structured data that is created.

My code is as follows:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'WC_Structured_Data', 'generate_product_data' ), 60 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dci_generate_product_data', 60 );
```

What I end up with is two lots of structured data for the product, one with the original ex Vat price and one with the inc Vat price I've added. So it looks like my remove action is not working correctly. Does any one have any idea why this might be!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got around this by changing my overriding function from:

```
WC()->structured_data->set_data( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', $markup, $product ) );
```

to:

```
WC()->structured_data->set_data( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', $markup, $product ), true );
```

This is replacing , rather than adding when calling set_data on the structured data object and is giving me the desired affect.